# PHP email code not working! Mail received as 'Array'

Tags: php, email, web

I'm developing a html landing page and below there is problem with the output of below code. Please help!

**Formdata.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0) {

$email_from = "Mail for Loans Direct";
$email_to = "archatish@gmail.com";
$mail_subject = "Mail";
$sender_name = $_POST["sendername"]; 
$sender_phone = $_POST["senderphone"];
$sender_address = $_POST["senderemail"]; 
$sender_message = $_POST["sendermessage"];

// prepare email body text
$Body = "Name: ";
$Body .= $sender_name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Mobile No.: ";
$Body .= $sender_phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email Id: ";
$Body .= $sender_address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Customer Message ";
$Body .= $sender_message;
$Body .= "\n";

echo "Debug Data " . $sender_name . $sender_phone . $sender_address . $sender_message . $Body;

$headers = "From:<$sender_address>\n";
$success = mail($email_to, $mail_subject, $Body, $headers);
// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="form-data/formdata.php" class="form-widget">

<input class="form-control" data-label="Name" required data-msg="Please enter name." type="text" name="sendername" placeholder="Enter your name">
<input class="form-control" data-label="Email" required data-msg="Please enter email." type="email" name="senderemail" placeholder="Enter your email">
<input class="form-control" data-label="Phone" required data-msg="Please enter phone number." type="text" name="senderphone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
<textarea class="form-control" data-label="Message" name="sendermessage" placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Apply</button>
</form>
```

**Mail Received as below:**

Name: Array
Mobile No.: Array
Email Id: Array
Customer Message Array

Comment: Is the 'Debug Data' you print correct, or does it also have 'Array':s ?

Comment: `echo "Debug Data " . $sender_name . $sender_phone . $sender_address . $sender_message . $Body;` what it outputs?

Comment: your code works fine at my end. Something you missed to show from your code.

Comment: print_r($_POST) output ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the post data values using print_r($_POST) so you can able identify the issue.